# I want to delete all png files from server where name start with pub_

Tags: php

which is this that delete all png from our server but only those png that start with pub_. i don't know how to do this i were searching it on google and on stackoverflow all dy long but didn't find any help.

This is hwat i did so far

```
$directory = "/home/html/domain.com/public/mydir/testDIR/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.png");
//print each file name
foreach ($images as $image)
{
 echo $image."<br />";
}
```

it returns me all png including those with name pub_xyz.png, now i want to delete all of pub_xyz.png plz help me thanks.

Comment: Have you tried "pub_*.png" with the glob command on line 2 of your code?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/unlink  and then why not `glob('pub_*.png')` instead?

Comment: Thanks guys i did glob($directory . "pub_*.png"); and got what i want thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$directory = "/home/html/domain.com/public/mydir/testDIR/";
$images = glob($directory . "pub_*.png");

foreach ($images as $image){
  echo $image."<br />";
}
```

if that prints everything correctly, add

```
unlink($directory . $image);
```

to your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks Prisoner i did as you said (except $directory . $image i only used $image to unlink ) and my problem is solved thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) for that:

```
if(strpos($image, 'pub_') === 0) {
    // delete image
}
```

The code above checks if the substring `pub_` is at position 0 in the original string meaning that it starts with it. If so the file should be deleted